# Circular Dependency Error autoloading constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting the error "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant API::V1::CitysController" when I try load my api page. Everything I've searched seems to suggest their might be a typo but I don't think there is one.

My routes:

```
namespace :api , defaults: {format: 'json'} do
 namespace :v1 do
  resources :citys
 end
end
```

my controller is in app/controllers/api/v1/citys_controller.rb

Theres nothing in it really at the moment

```
class Api::V1::CitysController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :json

 def index

 end
end
```

Not sure what else is relevant to the problem? It should just load a blank page without any errors when I go to localhost:3000/api/v1/citys

Added routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
  pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)            pages#home
        root GET    /                                pages#home
api_v1_citys GET    /api/v1/citys(.:format)          api/v1/citys#index {:format=>"json"}
             POST   /api/v1/citys(.:format)          api/v1/citys#create {:format=>"json"}
 new_api_v1_city GET    /api/v1/citys/new(.:format)      api/v1/citys#new {:format=>"json"}
edit_api_v1_city GET    /api/v1/citys/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/citys#edit {:format=>"json"}
 api_v1_city GET    /api/v1/citys/:id(.:format)      api/v1/citys#show {:format=>"json"}
             PATCH  /api/v1/citys/:id(.:format)      api/v1/citys#update {:format=>"json"}
             PUT    /api/v1/citys/:id(.:format)      api/v1/citys#update {:format=>"json"}
             DELETE /api/v1/citys/:id(.:format)      api/v1/citys#destroy {:format=>"json"}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce...Do you have a view?  What are you trying to render as a response?

Comment: No view. Dont think I need one right? Its just an api for a javscript frontend. I didn't set up any actual responses yet.I was just trying to get the routes right first. There's no models yet either. That shouldnt be a problem though I think? It should at least go to a blank page without an error.

Comment: It might not be the crux of your problem, but you do need to render *something* or else you would get a missing template error (it won't render a blank page, unless you explicitly have a blank template/return).  I set up a dummy rails app and copied what you posted to a 't' and didn't get the Circular error,  I rendered the text "It works!" and sure enough, I saw "It works!".  So something else is breaking.  What is the result of `rake routes`?

Comment: Added something to render. Didnt change anything. I added the routes to the original question. I also get the error "Unable to autoload constant API::V1::CitysController, expected /vagrant/trip_picker/app/controllers/api/v1/citys_controller.rb to define it" the first time I load the page. When I refresh it goes to the circular error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the error says it is looking for `API::V1::CitysController` class in your `citys_controller.rb` file and you have `Api::V1::CitysController`.  So first and foremost change the name of your class to `API::V1::CitysController` (note the capitalized 'API').  That should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: I should note that this is an anomaly.  I'm not sure why it's expecting `API` instead of `Api`, and it's the exact opposite on my machine.  It could be a OS issue, or the version of Rails, or some gem that's installed, it's difficult to tell.  I'll try to look into it some more.

Comment: I had an infliction I copied I guess without fully knowing what it did? ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.acronym 'API'
 end I removed that and Api works they way it should now.

Comment: Ahh, well there we go.  Thanks for the follow up!